# DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context

Tags: file-system-access-api

When attempting to access a file using the `getFile()` method of a [FileSystemFileHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle), this error can occur: `DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`

This code works:

```
async function getTheFile() {
  // open file picker
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker(pickerOpts);

  // get file contents
  const fileData = await fileHandle.getFile();
}
```

However if you store the `fileHandle` (using IndexedDB, for example) with the intent to persist access to the file even after a page refresh, it will not work. After refreshing the page, the `getFile()` method will throw the DOMException error.

What's going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When the page is refreshed (or all tabs for the app are closed) the browser no longer has permission to access the file.

There is a [queryPermission()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle/queryPermission) method available for the `FileSystemHandle` that can be used to determine whether the file can be accessed before attempting to read it.

Example from [a helpful web.dev article](https://web.dev/file-system-access/):

```js
async function verifyPermission(fileHandle, readWrite) {
  const options = {};
  if (readWrite) {
    options.mode = 'readwrite';
  }
  // Check if permission was already granted. If so, return true.
  if ((await fileHandle.queryPermission(options)) === 'granted') {
    return true;
  }
  // Request permission. If the user grants permission, return true.
  if ((await fileHandle.requestPermission(options)) === 'granted') {
    return true;
  }
  // The user didn't grant permission, so return false.
  return false;
}
```

This function will return true once the permission === `granted` or re-prompt the user for access if permission is either `denied` or `prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you will have to [grant permissions](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#stored-file-or-directory-handles-and-permissions) each time you retrieve a handle from indexedDB, serializing seems to lose the permission

Comment: That's true, however I store the `File` object in indexedDB as a cache to avoid prompting the user. Files can be big, so it should be used sparingly.